# How do I return a boolean value to another method?

Tags: java, methods, boolean

I'm trying to make a simple story adventure text game. I created a boolean called 'key' and set it to false. In a seperate method, if the user types 1, it is supposed to set the key boolean to true and return the value of true to the start method. However, I'm not sure how I would do this. Here is the code of the two methods:

Start method:

```
static void start() throws IOException  {
    boolean key = false;
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("You are in a dark room with 3 doors.");
    System.out.println("Pick 1. 2. or 3.");



    int number;

    number = in.nextInt(); 

    if(number == 1) {

        room1();


        }



    }
}
```

Method that changes the value of key to true:

```
     static void room1() throws IOException {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("You have picked room 1.");
    System.out.println("You find a dead man's corpse.");
    System.out.println("Do you: 1. Loot the corpse or 2. Go back to the starting area");


    int number;

    boolean key; 
    number=in.nextInt();
    if(number == 1) {
        System.out.println("You find a key to another door, perhaps back at the starting area?");
         key = true;
        start();
    }

}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: where is your separate method?

Comment: I apologize, not sure what you're referring to.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with declaring `key` in the `start` method is that it goes out of scope outside that method.  You cannot access it from another method such as `room1`.

To keep the `key` variable in scope, you must declare it as a class variable, outside of any methods, but inside the class itself.  It must be `static` so your `static` methods can access it.

Comment: Anytime I write public static boolean key = false inside the class itself  I just get an invalid modifier error.

Answer (score 0):

Just thinking a little more broader.  In your game, you will have at least 1 key per dungeon so, it would make a little more sense to have a private array of "keys" and use accessors to test whether your character has a dungeon key or not.

hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

As the people already answered, change the *key* variable to **global**, meaning declare that variable in the beginning of the class and then use it in your method.

*Example:*

```
public class Example {
public static boolean key = false;
}
```

Also, i encourage you to use switch-case for the choices you're about to make:

```
int number;

number = in.nextInt(); 

switch(number) {
case 1:
    room1();
    break;
case 2:
    room2();
    break;
default:
    break;
    }
```